# How to apply common format for controls using skin or jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I don't know much about skins. I want to apply a common format for text boxes, labels or grid-view in my project.

Is it possible by applying a Skin to a project? Or there is any other way to apply same functionality with jquery.

Comment: Give a try to these  search results http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=themes+in+asp.net&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the project -> Add -> ASP.Net Folder and add a Theme. Name it as you wish.
2. Right click your skin -> Add -> New item -> .skin
3. In the skin file, write the Skins for your controls.
   ex.

   ```
       <asp:TextBox 
            runat="server"
            BackColor="IndianRed"
            ForeColor="Snow"
            Font-Size="X-Large"
            Font-Italic="true"
            Font-Underline="true"
            // optional
            SkinID = "textbox_skin"
            >
       </asp:TextBox>
   ```

   Define the **SkinID** property - It allows you to apply the skin only on the needed controls later. If the skin should apply on all the controls in your project don't define it.
4. In your `@Page` directive there are two options to add the skin, depending on your design:

   - Add `Theme="your_skin_name"`, if you want the defined skin in your *.skin file to override the already existing style that the controls have.  For example if the control already has some css defined, with Theme="your_skin_name" they won't be taken into account anymore.
   - Add `StylesheetTheme="your_skin_name"` if you want to keep your already defined styles, and add from the skin only the ones that are missing.

   - If you want to define by your self, which controls get the style from the Theme/Skin, than use the SkinID like this in your *.aspx file:

   `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
                runat="server" 
                SkinID="textbox_skin">
        </asp:TextBox>`

***note***: if you define the SkinID on a control skin in the *.skin file, than in the *.aspx you have to define it also, on the corresponding controls that the skin should apply to.